# Get Multiple CheckBoxList Values In WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have CheckListBox(Multi Select ListBox).

My CheckListBox has,

```
MyMultiListComboBox.DataSource = context.GetValues();
MyMultiListComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
MyMultiListComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
```

I try to get selected multi values like below,

```
var Values = MyMultiListComboBox.SelectedValue;
```

However i get only first selected value.**How can i get all selected values** in WinForms c# ?

Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type that `context.GetValues()` returns?

Comment: I list data of my customers

Comment: please be specific, `List<Customer>` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
var values = MyMultiListComboBox.SelectedItems.Cast<Customer>()
                                .Select(x=>x.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data Type of the list context.GetValues() is returning you can use `SelectedItems` on the CheckListBox and then just `ConvertAll` to the type that is required for your list.